# remove trailing value using sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have a value like 127.00 and want to remove those 00. how can i do this using sql not from code.

Comment: What datatype is that value?? If you're storing this in a e.g. `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` column - forget it: that's just the way SQL Server stores these values. If you're storing this in a VARCHAR field - shouldn't you rather store it as a number ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast it to an INTEGER:

```
select cast(127.00 as INTEGER)
```

Or, if it is a varchar, you can substring it:

```
select substring('127.00', 1, charindex('.', '127.00')-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Strip String
Declare @value VarChar(50)
Set @value = '127.00'
Select SubString(@value, 0, CharIndex('.', @value))

-- Convert From Numeric to Int
Declare @value Numeric(19,4)
Set @value = 127.00
Select Convert(Int, @Value)
```